# Font size issue from flash to php

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

We have a serious issue while saving images from a flex editor

Our editor is adding some text to images and php script (imagick) is saving that image by receiving all parameters from Flex editor

The problem we think is because of the font measurement in flex and in php. In flex fontsize is calculated in pixels and in php it is calculated in points. Hence when we write a text "Hello" in flex with fontsize "10" and while we write the same text with same font size in php looks different

We tried to do some calculations for converting pixels to points but not working out properly.

Can anyone help us on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It 72 points per inch; and 96 pixels per inch

points = pixels * 72 / 96

You can test here also

http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/pixels-x-to-postscript-points-conversion.html

Comment: I am using imagmagick, according to php manual, imagettftext is taking font size as points from GD2.0 so it should be points